# Wondering if I can use mySQLs connection.threadID to continue running queries?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to web development, but I am building a tool to help us visualize the customers in our database in a more concrete way (basically a CRM of sorts). Its a web app using a node.js backend and Vue.js for the front end.

THE BIG QUESTION - I found a connection.threadId query that can be run. If I save this threadID in a cooke or JSON web token, can I use this to have each user uniquely querying the database? If you need additional information on my issue, continue reading.

Essentially the problem I am running into is authentication. We were able to get a dummy user create that has read only privileges to the database, but this doesnt help the account management team. I am trying to find a way for them to be able to login with their own credentials and then be able to run queries from my node.js (javascript) backend using a series of get and post requests.

I am able to get the user to login with the SQL password and they can run the initial query (that fires upon login) but they then cannot re-query the database if someone else logs in after them (I realized that my variables were all globally scoped on the server.) I then moved everything client side in JSON web tokens, but I had to hash the database password to be safe which leaves me with another problem. My hash and the original database hash do not match, and that is not something I'll ever get access to. Not really sure where else to go with this at this point.

Please ask if you need any additional information to assist.

Thanks!

Comment: how many types are you trying accommodate, a few (only user and account manager), or potentially a large set (>10)? Also, does your hosting environment support configuration variables (such as AWS, Heroku, or other cloud app hosting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't.

You also probably shouldn't use variables on the SQL server for a web app like this. If you can refactor those into variables you can schlep around in the user session (or POST parameters or whatever), you're much better off, being more stateless (as far as the server components are concerned) and all too.